# DataTables sort with mDataProp and fnRender from JSON

Tags: jquery, json, sorting, datatables

I am attempting to use `mDataProp`, `fnRender`, and `bUseRendered` to sort a column based on an ID, but display a Name.  I see that `bUseRendered` is deprecated and that the API suggests using `mData` and `mRender`, but with those I can't get any data to populate in my column.  Here is my code that kind of works, but does not render what I would like it too:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "sAjaxSource": "source.php",
    "aaSorting": [],
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp" : "NameID",
           "fnRender" : "Name",
           "bUseRendered": false},
        { "mDataProp" : "Priority"},
        { "mDataProp" : "Action"}
        ]
    } );
} );
```

And here is my attempt using mData, but this will not populate my first column and gives me an error popup.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "sAjaxSource": "source.php",
    "aaSorting": [],
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData" : "NameID",
           "mRender" : "Name"},
        { "mDataProp" : "Priority"},
        { "mDataProp" : "Action"}
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Any ideas how to get it to display my `Name`, but sort by `NameID`?

Comment: I created a function for the `fnRender` to grab the `"Name"` from the row `aData`.  Will post fix later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "sAjaxSource": "source.php",
    "aaSorting": [],
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp" : "NameID",
          "bUseRendered" : false,
          "fnRender" : function(oObj) {
                       return oObj.aData["Name"];
                       }
        },
        { "mDataProp" : "Priority"},
        { "mDataProp" : "Action"}
        ]
    } );
} );
```